# Rails 5 testing POST request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tdd, integration-testing

I have this test:

```
test "invalid signup" do
  get signup_path
  assert_no_difference 'User.count' do
    post users_path, user: {
      name: '', email: '', password: '',
      password_confirmation:''
    }
  end
  assert_template 'users/new'
end
```

but when I run it with `rake test`, I see this error:

> Error: UsersSignupTest#test_invalid_signup: ArgumentError: unknown
>   keyword: user
>       test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:9:in block (2 levels) in '
>       test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:8:in block in '

How to pass data for POST method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code that you were supposed to copy:

```
assert_no_difference 'User.count' do
  post users_path, params: { user: { name:  "",
                                     email: "user@invalid",
                                     password:              "foo",
                                     password_confirmation: "bar" } }
end
```

The key-value pair `params: some_hash` is the second argument to `post()`--not the key-value pair `user: some_hash`.

The `params` hash is a pretty important concept in rails.